# Not printing what I wrote inside the brackets in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I'm trying to make a simple python program that I can generate random passwords with it but that's not the problem the problem is when I was trying to print my programs name (Password Generator) onto the terminal I wrote the P letter like below:

```
def logo():
  log ="""
  _________________
  |                \
  |                 \
  |                 /
  |----------------/ 
  |
  |
  |
  |
  """

  print(log)
logo()
```

But whenever I run the program it prints:

```
  _________________
  |                  |                   |                 /
  |----------------/ 
  |
  |
  |
  |
```

Can you tell me about the problem and how to solve it?

P.S : I'm new to python

Comment: Use two \ characters instead of 1, like so: \\.

Comment: Alternatively, add an `r` before the quotes, like this:  `log = r"""` .  That makes it a raw text string, so everything within is interpreted as you see it.